# why the detect first launch or not method does not work

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        guideTourViewController *guide=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GuideTour"];
        guide.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:guide animated:NO completion:nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever

    }

 }
```

Why the even if launch the app for the first time, the guideTourViewController still does not show up?

Comment: I tried use performSeugeWithIdentifier, which is not work either. Therefore it must means that there are something wrong with the way of detecting the first-time launch

Comment: does the code without any condition shows the guide view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like two consecutive transitions issue, If i am correct you may put in `else` part

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //
    guideTourViewController *guide=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GuideTour"];
    guide.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:guide animated:NO completion:nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
});
```

You may reduce the delay according to your need.

Hope this would work..